# react-native error - Check the render method of `App`

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, render

I was running my react-native expo managed project by `expo start` command and I don't know that what is wrong in my code that I got this error -

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

This is my code -

```
export default function App() {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'PoetsenOne-Regular': require('./assets/fonts/PoetsenOne-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else{
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.container}>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my stylesheet -

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontFamily: "PoetsenOne-Regular"
  },
});
```

Comment: What is your `AppLoading`?

Comment: @Konstantin It is a function which I have already imported and it has no problem with my code

Comment: Have you imported AppLoading correctly?

Comment: @AlexHill Yes, this was the real problem, I solved it myself earlier but still thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this myself, the problem was the if-else statement -

```
if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }
```

When I removed it the error itself resolved and the `return <AppLoading />;` was the main reason of error because it was not imported properly, I imported `import { AppLoading } from 'expo'` instead of `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading'`